# Frogs or crocodiles?

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, plagues-makkos, exodus

Regarding the plague of frogs, there are some commentaries that render the translation as crocodiles. Yet in the text it states the frogs actually entered the bodies of the Egyptians. Small frogs inserting themselves into the human body is tenable but crocodiles are large creatures which seems an unlikely scenario. How could crocodiles be a consideration given the description of them entering Egyptian bodies?

Comment: Where in the text does it say that

Comment: @DoubleAA ובכה ובעמך ובכל עבדיך יעלו הצפרדעים is the source. Though the literal translation is obviously not necessarily the meaning, it is where rashi brings that Midrash

Comment: Exodus 7:28-29 — 28And the Nile will swarm with frogs, and they will go up and come into your house and into your bedroom and upon your bed and into the house of your servants AND INTO YOUR PEOPLE, and into your ovens and into your kneading troughs;  
29 AND INTO YOUR PEOPLE AND INTO YOUR SERVANTS, THE FROGS WILL ASCEND.'"

Comment: @Ephraim77 it seems that you are using R. Shraga Silverstein's Rashi based translation - that may bias the reading towards a particular interpretation. Perhaps your question ought to be something more along the lines of "how do those interpreters that take the position that צפרדעים are crocodiles interpret/translate verses 7:28-29?"

Comment: That’s the crux of my question. I think it’s worded as you suggest.